# android-studio can't find an aidl interface for use in class

Tags: android, intellij-idea, aidl, android-studio

I have an interface defined in the aidl but I can't extend it or find it any way. The ide just tells me: **Can not resolve symbol 'KeyEventListener'**
Any idea how to fix this?

Additional infos:

- KeyEventListener is the name of the interface defined in KeyEventListener.aidl
- KeyEventListenerImpl is the class which extends the interface Stub
- KeyEventListener just contains one method named 'void doIt();' and is well formatted;

I know android-studio is some thing like a pre-alfa but like it very much and would be very happy if some one could halp me out on this!

[image]

Answer (score 17):

In my case `Clean` and `Rebuild` project solved my problem.

Answer (score 15):

If it's 2023 and you switched from gradle 7 to 8 then I might have a fix.

There is a gradle property called **buildFeatures.aidl**. It needs to be **true** to compile aidl files. In gradle version 7 [the default is true](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/BuildFeatures#aidl()). But the default has been changed [to false](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/BuildFeatures#aidl()) in gradle 8.

So if your aidl file is in the default app module you need to edit **app/build.gradle**. Please don't copy/paste but put the line "aidl true" at the right place in your file instead. The hierarchy is like this:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        aidl true
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 12):

You are probably best off having a look at [The Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure) for Android.

Gradle, by default, requires a particular directory structure. If you want to use Gradle with a directory structure that most Android devs are accustomed to, you'll need to put the following (from the above-mentioned link) inside the "android" block.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
}
```

After you've done this, do a clean and rebuild to be on the safe side.

Personally, I just adapt my projects to fit the new convention.

Comment: That is correct. If you are using the new structure, remember that aidl files now go in src/main/aidl and not src/main/java.

Comment: google should really add an infobox about this if it detects aidl elsewhere

Answer (score 4):

Created a directory aidl under src/main.

Then created the new aidl file package structure and moved aidl file into it.

Rebuilt and it was done.

[I followed this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22769862/1234913)