# How to reference external aidl file in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have two projects that communicate using a .aidl file.
Using eclipse I could simply reference the source folder and all worked as expected.
How can I do that in 'Android Studio'?? It seems a simple task, but for the life of me, I haven't discovered how?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: the aidl file is not part of either project, it is referenced by both.

Comment: I'm referring to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596352/android-studio-cant-find-an-aidl-interface-for-use-in-class

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [How to add link to file system in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863087/how-to-add-link-to-file-system-in-intellij-idea) there is no way to link to an external file in the way that eclipse allows.

What I did was to add the .aidl source to each project.  I don't like doing this as it forces one to keep them in sync.

Now considering adding a dependency from one to the other.

Comment: Unbelievable. And Android Studio is considered to better than Eclipse???