# How to add link to file system in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

When adding new file in Eclipse, there is an option to add as a link to a file from outside of the project (anywhere in the hard drive). Option is a checkbox called "Link to file in the file system" under the advanced options.

So where is this option in IntelliJ? Or more spesifically in Android Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have this feature, you can't link individual files outside of the project.

Normally one just copies a file to a project.

In IntelliJ IDEA it's possible to add additional content roots to the module (`Add Content Root` in the `Project Structure`, `Module` settings). This way you can link additional directories to the project, but not individual files.

Android Studio uses Gradle for project build and any configuration performed in the Project Structure will not be used by Gradle. If you want to link additional directories/files, you will have to modify `build.gradle` files by hand.