# I can't display image in HTML through Thymeleaf in Spring

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I do an example from Spring in Action 5. I try to display the homepage with an image. When I start localhost:8080 I see the homepage, but don't see image on it.

I enter HTML from the book:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to...</h1>
    <img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And I add an image in my project in Eclipse: [image: project explorer]

Add HomeController class:

```
package tacos;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

On display, I get next: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why it doesn't work.

When I was adding an image in Eclipse, I clicked right button mouse on src/main/resources/static/images then New-File-Link to file in the file system... I don't move an image in my project catalog. I only created to link on my image in the filesystem.

[So I added an image. It is not right...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTn9n.png)

Comment: I've dragged and dropped the img file on intellij and didn't work I had delete it and copy paste on windows explorer to work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but using Intelij IDEA. To solve this I changed the line:
`<img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}"/>` to `<img src="../static/images/TacoCloud.png"/>` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083565/8370915).

`..` - refers to the [parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066464/8370915)

Notice: "*link to file in the file system*" option [doesn't support Intelij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16869281/8370915).