# Android Studio: How to import AIDL file from a different Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, aidl

One Android Studio project contains a no-activity service, to be communicated with via `IMyAidlInterface` (belonging to package com.example.tutorialspoint7.noactivity).

Another Android Studio project contains an activity-only application, for the sole purpose of testing the aforemention service (assume a different package, e.g. com.example.tutorialspoint7.aidlactivity)

Without any special configuration, the aidlactivity project does not know about the noactivity project and thus, any reference to IMyAidlInterface in aidlactivity gets *"Cannot resolve symbol IMyAidlInterface"*.

I searched for a way to let the aidlactivity project to know about that AIDL file, but all "solutions" I found were actually workarounds duplicating the file and adding it as in this example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16906355/5556250

So, I turned into manually tweaking the app's build.gradle by adding the following into it:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tutorialspoint7.aidlactivity"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += '../../NoActivity/app/src/main/aidl/com/example/tutorialspoint7/noactivity'
    }
}
```

I then synced it and, how wonderful, it is now part of the aidlactivity project:

[image]

But... AIDLActivity still gets *"Cannot resolve symbol IMyAidlInterface"*.

What do I need to do now to get it to recognize the file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836234/how-can-i-add-the-aidl-file-to-android-studio-from-the-in-app-billing-example

Comment: @Danieboy I already saw that SO post. The accepted answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17836495/5556250) is incompatible with **true** import (i.e. without duplicating and needing to sync later) as I outlined above. Unless I am missing something? Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem "worked around". Here is how:

1. I **undid** the manual addition into the app's build.gradle:

sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += '../../NoActivity/app/src/main/aidl/com/example/tutorialspoint7/noactivity'
    }

2. I **manually** created the folder `..\AIDLActivity\app\src\main\aidl\com\example\tutorialspoint7\noactivity`, and then **copied over** to there the original `IMyAidlInterface.aidl` file from the 'NoActivity' service project.
3. Adding `import com.example.tutorialspoint7.noactivity;` in AIDLActivity.java **doesn't work!!!** so... I worked around this by simply referencing `IMyAidlInterface` using its **fully qualified** name:

[image]

4. Gradle sync the projects
5. The AIDLActivity project now builds without any errors. :-)

Credits goes to this Jun 18, 2013 post by dominik2...@gmail.com: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56755#c1

---

Update: I managed to avoid the explicit fully qualified name ugliness by simply importing the specific interface, not the package (duh!):

[image]

All is well now but... Why do I have to keep copying the interface file whenever it changes in the original service, instead of just referencing it? I wish there were a way to reference (instead of copy) an AIDL file in Android Studio (version 2.2.3).