# Unable to import AIDL

Tags: android, aidl

I have created new AIDL after write click on android in android studio as below:

```
interface ICalculator {
/**
 * Demonstrates some basic types that you can use as parameters
 * and return values in AIDL.
 */
void basicTypes(int anInt, long aLong, boolean aBoolean, float aFloat,
        double aDouble, String aString);
}
```

But it is not importing in my service and getting "Can not resolve ICalculator"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android-studio can't find an aidl interface for use in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596352/android-studio-cant-find-an-aidl-interface-for-use-in-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must build the project first so the java file for this aidl can be generated and you can use it in your project